# getting a text appeared directly after the cin value is added without pressing enter

Tags: c++

Now I want to output the following "You Paid:" // and then after this text user should put a number after which I want this word "Dollars." appears directly without pressing enter

is this possible and how

Comment: how do you know when the user is finished typing? Do they want 1 dollar or 12 or maybe 123 dollars?

Comment: think about it, the enter key exists for a reason, the user has to signal somehow that input is finished, most of the time the new line is just a side-effect.

Comment: It's possible if the user will hit the **space** and the text get appended automatically. Because there's no condition set how long the user need to input, e.g. 3 letters.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible, since you need to press enter to tell the program that the input is ready. However, you could do something like this:

```cpp
int payment;
cout << "You paid:" << endl;
cin >> payment;
cout << payment << " Dollars." << endl;
```

That way, if you input, for example, 5, the console will look like this:

```
You paid:
5
5 Dollars.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I already tried this and it is not what I need. I believe what I need is a way to include the cin value in cout. is there anyway to do this in C++

Comment: @BandarMohamed You mean you don't want the input to appear in the console? Let's say, you don't want that loose 5 to show up? If that's the case, I think you can't do that, since that's just how the console works.